# proving group is infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, infinite-groups

Consider the group $G=\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^3=1 \rangle$.

 I would like to show that $G$ is infinite by finding a homomorphism $\phi :G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ and showing that this homomorphism is surjective. I am not sure how to define the map $\phi$.

Comment: Try thinking about what the abelianization of $G$ is.

Comment: Should say:  I don't think anything along the lines you propose will work.  In the abelianization, $ab$ has order $6$ so that group does not surject onto $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there was a homomorphism $f\colon G\to\mathbb{Z}$ like that. Since the only integer with a finite order is 0, it follows that $f(a)=0=f(b)$ because $f(a)^2=0=f(b)^3$. Then your surjective homomorphism would be constantly 0, and this is a contradiction.